# Trying to find absolute string using REFind

Tags: coldfusion

We have list of reserved keyword that we don't want our clients to be able to use in out system. So we perform a search using REFind.

Here is the code:

```
<cfset reservedKeywords = "stop,end,quit,cancel,help,test">
<cfset foundArray = REFind("(?i)(" & ListChangeDelims(reservedKeywords, "|") & ")"
                       , form.keyword, 1, true)>
<cfif foundArray.pos[1] gt 0>
    <cfoutput>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            alert('Keyword "#mid(form.keyword, foundArray.pos[1], foundArray.len[1])#" has been reserved.');
            history.go(-1);
        </script>
    </cfoutput>
   <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

So everything works great.... but we do run into a problem when a keyword is searched that has one of the reserved word IN the keyword. So if "Blended" is submitted, it will be flagged as having the reserved word "end".

Is there a way to perform an absolute search where it takes into account the whole keyword?

I've been trying to edit and play around with the code but just can't get it to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: When your `reservedKeywords` is a comma separated list, then why do you not use ColdFusion's own functionality to work with those? https://cfdocs.org/listfindnocase

Comment: So if you're only looking for exact matches with reserved words, why even do a REFind at all? Would a simple `listFindNoCase()` work?

Comment: listFindNoCase() will have the same problem, it will find "end" in the word "blended".  This should be a RegEx what looks for "words".

Comment: No, it won't. listFind() and listFindNoCase() will return the position in the list of a element that matches what is searched completely. So 'blended' will not be matched if you search for 'end' or vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, if `form.keyword` contains a *single* word, then @BernhardDöbler is right. A regex would work, but it's overkill.

Comment: That worked perfectly!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use listFindNoCase() instead of REFind().

The way you are currently checking is if one of the elements in the list matches form.keyword - which is why 'blended' gets tagged as 'reserved' when it shouldn't -  however, you should be checking if form.keyword matches any items in the list - a subtle, but important, distinction.

```
reservedWords = "stop,end,quit,cancel,help,test";
reservedWordUsed = listFindNoCase( reservedWords, form.keyword );
if( reserveWordUsed ){
    // do the JS stuff here
}
```